# Button or menu entry to clear the sculpting mask?

Tags: interface, sculpting, masking

A mask has been created:

[image]

The shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> will clear it.
Is there a button in the user interface? Or a menu entry?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK there is no proper button, the way to clear the mask without a keyboard shortcut is the menu entry Hide/Mask>Clear Mask.

Answer (score 4):

You can clear it using  ***Alt+M***

**EDIT**

[You have a button under Hide/Mask]

But its shortcut is ALT+M

On the bottom there's a list of Keyboard Shortcuts

http://blender-manual-i18n.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/sculpt_mode.html

Comment: It's already in the question: "The shortcut Alt+M will clear it".

Comment: My bad,my bad..

Comment: Due to a bug in 2.83.4 I am seeing that ALT-M left a poly selected, so I realized that menu Mask>Fill and then Mask>Invert was the only way to clear it fully.